# Symfony user sticky locale

Tags: symfony, locale

In the past two days I've been trying to make my custom `LocaleSubscriber`, a subscriber which is supposed to set user's locale to user's preference or to default.

```
<?php

namespace App\Event\Subscriber;

use App\Entity\Language;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

/**
 * Class LocaleSubscriber
 * @package App\Event\Subscriber
 */
class LocaleSubscriber
{
    /** @var EntityManagerInterface */
    private $entityManager;

    /** @var SessionInterface */
    private $session;

    /**
     * LocaleSubscriber constructor.
     *
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
     * @param SessionInterface $session
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->session       = $session;
    }

    /** {@inheritdoc} */
    public function onInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $user    = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

        if (null !== $user->getLocale()) {
            $this->session->set('_locale', $user->getLocale());
            $request->setLocale($user->getLocale());
        } else {
            /** @var Language $language */
            $language = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Language::class)->findOneBy(['defaultLang' => true]);
            $language = $language->getSlug();

            $this->session->set('_locale', $language);
            $request->setLocale($language);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do this system because all languages are listed in my database (Language is one of my entities) and I want to make this application easy to maintain and extend for non-technical users.

The problem is that after leaving this method, request's locale is back to `en` and the new locale is kept only in session.

I've dumped at the end of the function `dump($request, $this->session->all())` and both have the same language. Also, the priority in `services.yaml` is set to 15.

```
App\Event\Subscriber\LocaleSubscriber:
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onInteractiveLogin, priority: 15 }
```

Any idea why is not working? Did someone encountered the same problem? Any examples?

Comment: Use kernel.request for that. Works for me.

Comment: Ah I see sticky. On interactive.login only set session locale. On every subsequent kernel.request set locale on request based on that session value? Split up the logic into 2 event listeners.

Comment: @mblaettermann seems to work with two listeners. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, you're welcome!